# 'click' Event listener not working on small screen

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, click, addeventlistener

I have a table whose each row has an addEventlistener for click. The rows are selected fine on bigger screens, but in small screens some of the items cannot be selected.
I am using plain JavaScript for this. I have the respective media queries defined so that should not be  a problem in my opinion.

This is my code:

```js
var table_row = document.querySelectorAll('.table-row'); //all table rows
window.onload = () => { //clear the localstorage from previous sessions
  localStorage.clear();
  table_row.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
      //on click of a row
      id = element.getAttribute('data-id');
      state = element.getAttribute('data-state');
      if (state == 'off') {
        //unselected
        element.style.background = "#742173";
        element.style.color = "white";
        element.setAttribute('data-state', 'on');

        //changed the appearance of current element
        if (prev_element != null) {
          //revert changes to last selection
          console.log('prev_element:' + prev_element.childNodes[1].innerText);
          prev_element.style.background = "#f0efed";
          prev_element.style.color = "black";
          prev_element.setAttribute('data-state', 'off');
        }

        //setting current element ad prev_element
        prev_element = document.getElementById(id);
        console.log('prev_element:' + prev_element.childNodes[1].innerText);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<table align="center
        " id='space-table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Spacecraft name</td>
      <td> Origin</td>
      <td> Destination</td>
      <td>Price per person</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="table-row" id='row1' data-id="row1" data-state="off">
      <td>ax12</td>
      <td>Sector 3</td>
      <td>Sector 5A-12</td>
      <td>450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row" id='row2' data-id="row2" data-state="off">
      <td>ax13</td>
      <td>Crater34</td>
      <td>Sector 3</td>
      <td>145</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row" id='row3' data-id="row3" data-state="off">
      <td>ax14</td>
      <td>Crater 34</td>
      <td>Sector 3A-5</td>
      <td>250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row" id='row4' data-id="row4" data-state="off">
      <td>ax15</td>
      <td>Sector 5A-12</td>
      <td>LM-36 </td>
      <td>125</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row" id='row5' data-id="row5" data-state="off">
      <td>ax16</td>
      <td>Sector 5A-12</td>
      <td>Crater 34</td>
      <td>210</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row" id='row6' data-id="row6" data-state="off">
      <td>ax17</td>
      <td>Crater 34</td>
      <td>LM-36</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see how the screen size could affect the JavaScript. My guess is that your CSS for the small size is causing some of the items to overlap.

Comment: Thanks. Actually a text was overlapping with my table

Comment: Does it work if you remove all the CSS?